# BigQuery unexpected error when creating a table

Tags: google-bigquery, create-table

I am trying to create table for a project.  I have to csv filed save on my desktop.  I am following the course instructions for creating the table.  Every time I hit 'create table' I get an unexpected error has occured. Any help??

Comment: How are you trying to create the table (cli, ui, ddl)? What is the error you’re getting?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with exactly the same issue, I moved desired file to the google drive and when you are creating a table use option where you link files from drive, but since you are not loading the file but linking from drive you wont be able to preview the data but it's there run a query and you ll see it returns the data. Ciao.

Comment: Its not real clear what the OP error is.